# How to make non-unique Pandas column into a unique one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Jim','Bob','Tim','Sal','Mel'], 
                   'Time': [7,7,7,8,9], 
                   'Value':[15,13,17,6,27]})
Out[1]:
  Name  Time  Value
0  Jim     7     15
1  Bob     7     13
2  Tim     7     17
3  Sal     8      6
4  Mel     9     27
```

But I want `Time` to be a unique column in the data, still in numeric form. For example, the series of `7` in `Time` could be `7.00, 7.01, 7.02` or `7.0, 7.1, 7.2` etc. How could I transform this non-unique numeric Pandas column into a unique one that is still numeric?

Comment: Would any numbers be okay, so like `7.14, 7.18, 7.22` or is there utility in counting so that it's 7.1 (if fewer than 10) 7.01 (if fewer than 100). 7.001...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['Time'] += df.groupby('Time').cumcount() / 10
```

```
    Name    Time    Value
0   Jim     7.0     15
1   Bob     7.1     13
2   Tim     7.2     17
3   Sal     8.0     6
4   Mel     9.0     27
```

Comment: I think `cumcount` is the way to go. However I'd divide by `df.groupby('Time').size().max()` (assuming integer times) that way you don't get leakage into other times if there were more than 10 observations.

Answer (score 3):

Add random data

```
df.assign(Time=df.Time.add(np.random.rand(len(df)) / 10).round(2))

  Name  Time  Value
0  Jim  7.07     15
1  Bob  7.01     13
2  Tim  7.05     17
3  Sal  8.00      6
4  Mel  9.03     27
```

Answer (score 1):

if your index is `rangeindex`, use string to concat `index` to `Time`. Using this way instead of regular addition and division to avoid leakage of result to the number in front of dot.

```
df.Time = (df.Time.astype(str) + '.' + df.index.astype(str)).astype(float)

Out[1623]:
  Name  Time  Value
0  Jim   7.0     15
1  Bob   7.1     13
2  Tim   7.2     17
3  Sal   8.3      6
4  Mel   9.4     27
```